# Sort order for sqlite index

Tags: sqlite, sorting, indexing

There is sort order when creating index for sqlite.

https://sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

> Each column name or expression can be followed by one of the "ASC" or "DESC" keywords to indicate sort order.

So, there are three options: no-sort, ASC, DESC when creating index. Where is info about how I should use them? I cant find it.

I guess, if I use ASC or DESC in queries, I should add them to index. But should I add them both if they are both in different queries? Or should I just don't set sort order and it will select it itself?

What is a general rule for it?

Comment: What do you mean by "add them both"? I cannot imagine a syntax for doing that. "can be followed by **one of** the ".

Comment: @Yunnosch, one by one, two different indexes, one is ASC, other is DESC (and third is without sort order?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite can step through an index in both directions, so in general, the index order does not matter.

Comment: Why is it here then?

Comment: I'm not sure; it's possible that the capability to step backwards was added later.

Answer (score 11):

SQLite can scan an index in both directions. For an index on a single column, this means it can be used to sort in both `ASC` and `DESC` order.

[Reference](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_sorting_by_index):

> The Idx1 index is scanned from top to bottom (or from bottom to top if "ORDER BY fruit DESC" is used) in order to find the rowids for each item in order by fruit.

But for an index on more than one column, there are more than two directions that one might wish to sort the data. For instance, on a two column index, one might wish to sort via `ASC, ASC`; `ASC, DESC`; `DESC, DESC`; or `DESC, ASC` order.

If the index was created in `ASC, ASC` order, then sorting by `ASC, ASC` or `DESC, DESC` will be able to fully use the index. But sorting by `ASC, DESC` and `DESC, ASC` will not be possible solely using the index. That is why the index order may be specified.

For more info: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/order-by-asc-desc-nulls-last